# SARIMA with daily data

Tags: r, time-series

I am attempting (unsuccessfully) to make a SARIMA model from daily data.

```
sarima500011 <- sarima(sq.deaths, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 365)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

Error in makeARIMA(trarma[[1L]], trarma[[2L]], Delta, kappa) : 
  maximum supported lag is 350

I have four years worth of daily data (which I can send to anyone who requests it) but can't figure out what to do here. Are there any alternatives?

Thank you.

Comment: Your seasonal period is 1 day? Can you make it 1 week? Then it would fit.

Comment: So should I change the 365 to 52?

Comment: It depends on your data. If you aggregate your daily data into weekly data, then you can change it to 52 (if it has a weekly seasonal pattern, like a call-center company).

Comment: So I would have to reduce the data to weekly? There's no way to use daily date with a period of 1 year?

Comment: The question is if it makes sense or not, which depends on your data. In general it's not a good idea to model such a high seasonal period. **You're basically saying that the value today depends on the value one year ago**, which is odd. Check out the `forecast`package which has a lot of options for time series forecasting.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the seasonality of your data and how you want to model it. If your data is cyclical by week and you have daily data (7 data points per week), then you should use a kappa=7. If it's cyclical by month, then try 30.